# Convert String like *italic* to <i>italic</i> but do not convert if line breaks are within the asterisks limiters

Tags: php, regex

I have the following Regex in my PHP code:

```
// markers for italic set *Text*
if (substr_count($line, '*')>=2)
{
    $line = preg_replace('#\*{1}(.*?)\*{1}#', '<i>$1</i>', $line);
}
```

which works great.

However, when a `$line` holds a `<br>`, e.g.

```
*This is my text<br>* Some other text
```

Then the regex still considers the text and transforms it to:

```
<i>This is my text<br></i> Some other text
```

The goal is to not translate the text if a `<br>` is encountered. How to do that with a Regex - using a so called "negative lookahead" or how can the existing Regex be changed?

Note: Strings like `*This is my text*<br>Some other text<br>And again *italic*<br>END` should still be considered and transformed.

Idea: Or should I explode the `$line` and then iterate over the results with the regex?!

Comment: Have you considered using a Markdown parser such as [Parsedown](https://github.com/erusev/parsedown) instead of re-inventing the wheel? Or does your specific use-case have a good reason to do so?

Comment: Thanks for the tip/link. I need to go the long way as there is Markdown and other custom syntax that we use.

Comment: Parsedown uses for italic: ` '*' => '/^[*]{2}((?:\\\\\*|[^*]|[*][^*]*+[*])+?)[*]{2}(?![*])/s',` [sourcecode](https://github.com/erusev/parsedown/blob/master/Parsedown.php#L1967) ... which I don't understand. So I try to code things myself, that I understand.

Answer (score 3):

Using *match-what-you-don't-want and discard* technique, you may use this regex in PHP (PCRE):

```php
\*[^*]*<br>\*(*SKIP)(*F)|\*([^*]*)\*
```

and replace with `<i>$1</i>`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5sZahs/1)

**PHP code:**

```
$r = preg_replace('/\*[^*]*<br>\*(*SKIP)(*F)|\*([^*]*)\*/'), 
        "<i>$1</i>", $input);
```

**Explanation:**

- `\*`: Match a `*`
- `[^*]*`: Match 0 or more non-`*` characters
- `<br>`: Match `<br>`
- `\*`: Match closing `*`
- `(*SKIP)(*F)`: PCRE verbs to discard and skip this match
- `|`: OR
- `\*([^*]*)\*`: Match string enclosed by `*`s

Comment: @Avatar: Did this work out for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace matches of the regular expression

```
\*(?:(?!<br>)[^*])+\*
```

with

```
'<i>$0</i>'
```

where `$0` holds the matched string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qwiAI5/1)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
\*         # match '*'
(?:        # begin a non-capture group
  (?!<br>) # negative lookahead asserts that next four chars are not '<br>'
  [^*]     # match any char other than '*'
)+         # end non-capture group and execute one or more times
\*         # match '*'
```